# Plotting animated exchange (plotting directional edges)

Tags: r, graphing, animated

I once saw [this plot (LINK)](http://sappingattention.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/visualizing-ocean-shipping.html) on shipping trades.  I work with dialogue exchanges and thought it may be interesting to map this sort of exchange using R.

This is a larger question but I think it may be useful to the community at large.

Let's say we have 7 people sitting around a table like this:[image]

And I have recorded dialogue exchanges speaker talks and listener hears.  I've created a dummy data.frame with this sort of information.  here's the head:

```
  speaker receiver duration speaker.x speaker.y receiver.x receiver.y
1       D        A       16     0.626     0.163      0.755      0.741
2       E        D        3     0.391     0.161      0.626      0.163
3       A        B       25     0.755     0.741      0.745      0.517
4       B        E        6     0.745     0.517      0.391      0.161
5       B        C       45     0.745     0.517      0.737      0.251
6       E        F       37     0.391     0.161      0.258      0.285
```

**I'd like to create animated arrows (from speaker to receiver) that are colored by speaker and weighted (time/duration and length and/or thickness) and animated in the same fashion as the shipping data (row number is the order in which the speech occurs).**  I think that perhaps the animation package may be useful here but have no clue.  Maybe this isn't possible with R currently (as indicated by Ben Schmidt's statement, *"I've been hoping I might be able to give up on ArcGIS for the next map project I do and keep everything in R--I'm not convinced after this experience that it will be possible"*).

I think many people in many fields could use this sort of mapping of exchanges, it just happens that I'm interested in an exchange of dialogue.  Eventually I'd plot this on top of a raster image but that's the easy part.

**Here's the data and plots this far.**

```
#the data
the_table <- data.frame(
    xmin = .3,
    xmax = .7,
    ymin = .2,
    ymax = .8
)

points <- structure(list(x = c(0.754594594594595, 0.744864864864865, 0.736756756756757, 
    0.626486486486486, 0.391351351351351, 0.258378378378378, 0.261621621621622
    ), y = c(0.741172932330827, 0.517052631578947, 0.250706766917293, 
    0.163007518796992, 0.161383458646617, 0.284812030075188, 0.494315789473684
    )), .Names = c("x", "y"))


mapping <- data.frame(person=LETTERS[1:7], points)

set.seed(10)
n <- 120
dat <- data.frame(id = 1:n, speaker=sample(LETTERS[1:7], n, TRUE),
     receiver=sample(LETTERS[1:7], n, TRUE),
    duration=sample(1:50, n, TRUE)
)
dat <- dat[as.character(dat$speaker)!=as.character(dat$receiver), ]

dat <- merge(merge(dat, mapping, by.x=c("speaker"), by.y=c("person"), sort=FALSE), 
    mapping, by.x=c("receiver"), by.y=c("person"), sort=FALSE)
names(dat)[5:8] <- c("speaker.x", "speaker.y", "receiver.x", "receiver.y")
dat <- dat[order(dat$id), c(2, 1, 4:8)]
rownames(dat) <- NULL

#the plot
ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=mapping, aes(x=x, y=y), size=10) +
    geom_text(data=mapping, aes(x=x, y=y, label=as.character(person)), 
        color="blue") +
    ylim(-.2, 1.2) + xlim(-.2, 1.2) + 
    geom_rect(data=the_table, aes(xmax = xmax, xmin=xmin, 
        ymin=ymin, ymax = ymax), fill="gray80")
```

I'm not married to ggplot2 but am partial to it, and it seems that many of these sorts of plots use ggplot2.

Comment: You might not be, but I'm married to ggplot2 :)

Comment: Try the `igraph` package

Comment: @Gary [I know about igraph](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/igraph-and-structured-text-exploration/) but to my knowledge it does not do animation.

Comment: Where does the animation come in? Does only one person speak at a time, or is there a start and end time for each `speech`

Comment: @mnel Good question.  Right now I'm starting easy/small with assuming one person speaks at a time.  Eventually I'd like to move to multiple speakers at once and a speaker directing to multiple receivers. But That's a project.  This question was already large enough so I kept it small.  But yes assume the animation comes in from one vector appearing right after another (row by row).

Comment: Something like `geom_segment(data = talking,aes(x= speaker.x, y= speaker.y, xend = receiver.x, yend = receiver.y, size = duration, colour = speaker), arrow = arrow())`

Comment: If you're willing to step outside R, I think it's pretty easy to stitch image files together into a movie using `ffmpeg`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829113/ffmpeg-create-a-video-from-images

Comment: @Marius It's really easy to stitch together frames in R using the animation package... there's no need to step outside of R if you're capable making the images from within R.

Comment: @Marius I found out animation has a function, `saveVideo` that uses ffmpeg to make an mp4 movie.  Your thinking was on the right track but the animation package does so much more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the animation package and `geom_segment` this is reasonably straight forward

My only issue thus far is getting a scale for the size to work reasonable

I've saved the talking data.frame as `talking`

```
library(animation)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(grid)         ## for arrow
library(ggplot2)      
# scale the duration (not ideal)
talking$scale_duration <-scale(talking$duration, center = FALSE)
# ensure that we have different colours for each speaker

ss <- levels(talking$speaker)

speakerCol <- scale_colour_manual(values = setNames(brewer.pal(n=length(ss), 'Set2' ), ss), guide = 'none')

# the base plot with the table and speakers (and `talking` base dataset)
base <- ggplot(data = talking, aes(colour = speaker)) +
  geom_point(data=mapping, aes(x=x, y=y), size=10, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data=mapping, aes(x=x, y=y, label=as.character(person)), 
    inherit.aes = FALSE, color="blue") +
  ylim(-.2, 1.2) + xlim(-.2, 1.2) + 
  geom_rect(data=the_table, aes(xmax = xmax, xmin=xmin, 
      ymin=ymin, ymax = ymax), fill="gray80", inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  speakerCol
 oopt <- ani.options(interval = 0.5)

# a function to create the animation


pp <- function(){
  print(base)
  interval = ani.options("interval")
  for(n in rep(seq_along(talking$duration), each = talking$duration))){
    # a segment for each row
    tn <- geom_segment(aes(x= speaker.x, y= speaker.y, xend = receiver.x, yend = receiver.y), arrow = arrow(), 
                       data =talking[n, ,drop = FALSE])
    print(base + tn)
    ani.pause()
  }
}
```

use `saveGIF(pp(), interval = 0.1)` to export a GIF animation etc

Comment: Nice answer.  Very thorough.  Animation is easier to do than I had anticipated.  Thank you.  Now I'll start working on some more complicated circumstances but I just need to play with this for a while.

Comment: @Tyler -- it was easier than I anticipated as well!

Comment: I think your animation shows one frame per exchange rather than being 'real time' and showing each frame for the length of the `duration` variable for that exchange. Did you mean to call `ani.pause(interval)` in there somewhere?

Comment: @spacedman, good point. Was making duration = size. Edit far better (I hope, untested)

Comment: @mnel is there any need for this line `oopt <- ani.options(interval = 0.5)`

Comment: @TylerRinker to restore it after I guess, something like `ani.options(oopt)`.