# animation: remove dots keep control panel

Tags: r, animation

I've been playing with the animation package lately.  Pretty nifty stuff but in the use of `saveHTML` I get a control panel with a green dot for every image (see below) and I have a ton of images.  How can I make the green dots go away but keep the control panel?

I asked a related question yesterday so the minimal working example is [there (my data set and mnel's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286380/plotting-animated-exchange-plotting-directional-edges).

Here's the code I'm using to make the html file:

```
saveHTML(pp(), autoplay=FALSE, loop=FALSE, verbose=FALSE, outdir = "new")
```

The animation help manual says *see the reference for a complete list of available options* but I can not figure out how to do what I've asked above.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to remove the 'navigator' option from 'controls'.  Try adding this to the parameter list: `single.opts = "'controls': ['first', 'previous', 'play', 'next', 'last', 'loop', 'speed'], 'delayMin': 0"`

to get something like:

```
saveHTML(pp(), autoplay=FALSE, loop=FALSE, 
         verbose=FALSE, outdir = "new", 
         single.opts = "'controls': ['first', 'previous', 'play', 'next', 'last', 'loop', 'speed'], 'delayMin': 0")
```

The default list includes 'navigator' so we're just removing that option.  You can reorder these options too if you want.

Comment: +1 I'll also point to `single.opts` in `?saveHTML`, and recommend a search for "navigator" on [this page](https://github.com/brentertz/scianimator) (which is also linked to in `?saveHTML`),

Comment: That's it Dason.  I viewed the page Josh linked to before posting but wasn't able to understand how to make this information work. Thanks for connecting the dots.